# Compiler gcc required when installing perl modules for Bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

I encountered the following error when attemtping to install the perl modules for Bugzilla in a Solaris 10 server. You can see that i have already set the path for gcc and make already.

Can anyone advise?

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/sbin:/opt/csw/gcc3/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:/usr/sfw/bin:/opt/csw/mysql5/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/sfw/bin/gcc"
export PATH


 /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
```

> ERROR: Using install-module.pl requires that you install a compiler,
>   such as gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Cygwin, but it was fixed after I installed **gcc4** (I had only gcc3 before).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below msg: Hope it helpful to you! Good luck!

Ivan R. Says:
July 30th, 2006 at 12:01 am 
You should checkout perlgcc(1), which is specifically for dealing with the situation. You’ll need /usr/perl5/bin in PATH ( and /usr/perl5/man in MANPATH ).

Ivan.

cos Says:
July 30th, 2006 at 12:30 am 
See also the “Solaris-PerlGcc” module - you end up with a “perlgcc” command you use when you run CPAN. a tiny bit more fiddly perhaps, but works just as well.

http://search.cpan.org/~aburlison/Solaris-PerlGcc-1.3/

Andrew Gallagher Says:
August 1st, 2006 at 5:25 pm 
The perlgcc module will not work with perl 5.8.4. See the README for Solaris-PerlGcc.

Andrew Gallagher Says:
August 1st, 2006 at 5:30 pm 
perlgcc is included in solaris 10. /usr/perl5/bin/perlgcc

David Says:
April 5th, 2007 at 7:37 pm 
perlgcc failed to install PathTools-3.24 on my sparc Solaris 10 system.
I also got make errors when I tried matty’s edits in Config.pm. Gonna try installing Sun Studio, see how that works.

Tmack Says:
January 9th, 2008 at 7:53 pm 
You might also need to edit Config_heavy.pl (in the same dir as the Config.pm) to edit the flags and make CPAN.pm happy, since it is req’d in Config.pm. Another flag that might need removal is -xarch=386, it still complains with that present on an x2200.

Tmack Says:
January 9th, 2008 at 8:37 pm 
wrt previous comment, the perl version I used requiring the extra steps is not the one installed w/solaris, but a blastwave package, which does things a little different (thus the extra files and flags) and uses perl 5.8.8 .