# gcc required when installing Bugzilla on diskstation

Tags: perl, gcc

I'm trying to install Bugzilla but encounter a Perl problem.

When installing required Perl modules, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Using install-module.pl requires that you install a compiler, such as gcc.
```

gcc 4.2.3 is installed and in the path. I'm using perl v 5.8.6 OS: Linux DiskStation 2.6.32.12

Another thread on Stackoverflow refers to PerlGcc but it seems to work on Solaris only.

How can I make Perl find gcc?

Comment: I'd start by checking the exact condition for which that message is issued by grepping the distro you're installing, and if necessary, the directories in `@INC`. Sorry, can't look into this right now.

Comment: The files /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.6/MARVELL_88F6281/Config.pod and /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.6/MARVELL_88F6281/Config.pm refers to gcc e.g. cc="/usr/local/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc". There is no directory /usr/local/arm-none-linux-gnueabi

Comment: So the compiler used to build Perl isn't present. Maybe you should install a local build of Perl (using [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) or not). You wouldn't have this problem, and you wouldn't be confined to such an ancient version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're talking about [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494929/compiler-gcc-required-when-installing-perl-modules-for-bugzilla). Assuming that the guy talking about the version of gcc being relevant was onto something, could you check that you don't have an older version of gcc lying around somewhere higher in the path with

```
$ which gcc
```